# Хорошие книги по JavaScript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, книги

Хочу изучить более детально интернет-технологии, в данном случае Frontend разработку. Вот хочу попросить посоветовать хорошие книги по JavaScript...

Я смотрел много вариантов. Но хотелось бы книгу не просто по написанию кода. Например, напишите это, получите то. А хотелось бы, чтобы сначала основы объяснялись, то есть как вообще работает данный язык, как он взаимодействует с браузером и подобные вопросы, а не просто выучить синтаксис и писать, не понимая, как оно реально внутри работает, а потом при первой же ошибке входить в ступор и бегать по форумам с просьбой написать код за тебя.

Посоветуйте, кто что знает. Желательно на английском.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список рекомендованной литературы из книги Стояна Стефанова «JavaScript Patterns», O'REILLY ISBN 978-5-93286-208-7, ISBN 978-0-596-80675-0 (англ):

- «Object-Oriented JavaScript» Стоян Стефанов (Stoyan Stefanov) (Packt Publishing)
  Предисловие 17
- «JavaScript: The Definitive Guide», Дэвид Флэнаган (David Flanagan)
  (O’Reilly)
- «JavaScript: The Good Parts», Дуглас Крокфорд (Douglas Crockford) (O’Reilly)
- «Pro JavaScript Design Patterns», Росс Гермес (Ross Hermes) и Дастин Диаз (Dustin Diaz) (Apress)
- «High Performance JavaScript», Николас Закас (Nicholas Zakas) (O’Reilly)
- «Professional JavaScript for Web Developers», Николас Закас (Nicho- las Zakas) (Wrox)